# Why I can't set width of fixed 100%

Tags: html, css

I have problem with fixed element, I wan't to set her width 100% relative to the second parent div .container
http://jsfiddle.net/q7wcam7x/2/

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="header">
        <div class="fixed">
            !
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container{
    width:300px;
    position:relative;
    margin:auto;

}
.header{
  position:relative;
    border:1px solid red;
    height:300px;
}
.fixed{
    position:fixed;
    width:inherit;
    height:10px;
    background-color:blue;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This isn't possible with position:fixed, because fixed positioning is relative to the *viewport* (or the "screen").

However, this could be done with position:absolute, which causes the element to position itself relative to the closest parent that has the position property set on it:

http://jsfiddle.net/q7wcam7x/6/

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="header">
        <div class="fixed">
            dasdasdasdadddddddds
            dsa
            asdd
            asd
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.container{
    width:300px;
    position:relative;
    margin:auto;
}
.header{
    border:1px solid red;
    height:300px;
}
.fixed{
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:10px;
    background-color:blue;
}
```

If the above is not what you're looking for, maybe this will help you find a solution to your problem:

http://jsfiddle.net/q7wcam7x/7/

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="stickyHeader">THIS IS A HEADER</div>
    <div class="scrollableContent">SCROLLABLE CONTENT
        <br/>SCROLLABLE CONTENT
        <br/>SCROLLABLE CONTENT
        <br/>SCROLLABLE CONTENT
        <br/>SCROLLABLE CONTENT
        <br/>SCROLLABLE CONTENT
        <br/>SCROLLABLE CONTENT
        <br/>SCROLLABLE CONTENT
        <br/>SCROLLABLE CONTENT
        <br/>SCROLLABLE CONTENT
        <br/>SCROLLABLE CONTENT
        <br/>SCROLLABLE CONTENT
        <br/>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.container {
    width: 200px;
    height: 150px;
    overflow:hidden;
    border: gold solid 2px;
}
.stickyHeader {
    height: 20px;
    background: white;
}
.scrollableContent {
    height: 130px;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: it's not working in my big project,  because it's halves content.

Comment: @ml92 I'm not sure I understand what you mean by halves. Would you mind elaborating?

Comment: I didn't solved problem :( , man with absolute I can't swet div only on top fixed, I may to use fixed

Comment: Sorry man, be specific on what you want and what you can use. It is really hard to help you like this!

Comment: @ml92 I'd like to help you out, but I honestly am not sure what you are looking for. A more specific example might help

Comment: I want inside container to set width of child div 100%, and when scrolling i want to stay that div in first position (fixed)

Comment: @ml92 I'm still not fully sure what you're looking for, but I've updated my first jsFiddle to resemble yours more closely. If that one doesn't help, maybe you should have a look at my second jsFiddle

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
.fixed{
    position:fixed;
    left: 0;
    right: 0
    width:inherit;
    height:10px;
    background-color:blue;
}
```

Comment: Please consider editing your post to add more explanation about what your code does and why it will solve the problem. An answer that mostly just contains code (even if it's working) usually wont help the OP to understand their problem. It's also recommended that you don't post an answer if it's just a guess. A good answer will have a plausible reason for why it could solve the OP's issue.